# Output / show / print Meteor Simple Schema of Entities

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor, simple-schema, meteor-collections

I have a Meteor app and generated some DB Collections which have a SimpleSchema https://github.com/aldeed/simple-schema-js attached.

```
Cards = new Mongo.Collection('cards');

Cards.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  title: {
    type: String,
  },
  archived: {
    type: Boolean,
    autoValue() {
      if (this.isInsert && !this.isSet) {
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
  completed: {
    type: Boolean,
    autoValue() {
      if (this.isInsert && !this.isSet) {
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
```

And so on.

Is there a function something like: `log( Cards.schema )` which outputs all the defined properties / fields and their datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can do as below at the ***client side***, at the place you have subscribed the `Cards` collection.

e.g.

```
Template.xyz.onRendered(function(){
  console.log(Cards._c2._simpleSchema);
});
```

Comment: what's the purpose of `_c2` ?